# Switching Laravel assets between http and https in local and production

Tags: https, laravel, laravel-4

I'm developing an application that will eventually need to be fully HTTPS but I'm temporarily developing locally on HTTP.

If I use `URL::to_asset('path', false)` locally then I'd have to go and change every instance of that to true when I switch to HTTPS.

At the moment I'm thinking a `Config::get('app.https', true)` as the second argument would be the easiest way around this but I was wondering whether there's a more system-wide approach for ensuring your assets follow the routes (for example if I had an application that had partial usage of HTTPS routes it would be nice if Laravel automatically worked out whether you're on a HTTPS route and returned the correct asset link).

Or is it possible to get assets to use the `"//domain.tld/path/to/something"` approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of manually setting it through configs you could use `Request::secure()` to check, if the request is done over HTTPS.

reference: [laravel request information](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that - definitely neater than using a config::get :)

Comment: but of course adding `Request::secure()` in each line assets is not a good idea! right?

Comment: I guess you have to, but `Request::secure()` for instance is a very cheap call. also you could use it in collaboration with `asset('url', Request::secure())` (http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_asset)

Answer (score 4):

Set HTTPS 'on' or 'off' in your web server's environment. That should propagate to Laravel, and result in http: or https: URL generation.

It may be worth adding that we run our Laravel apps on Elastic Beanstalk. EB terminates SSL at the Load Balancer, so Laravel "thinks" it's HTTP, when it's not. We use redirects to ensure all traffic is HTTPS from the outside, and set HTTPS=ON in the EB Dashboard settings so that assets aren't subject to redirects.

Answer (score 4):

Tested on Laravel 5x, you can do like this:

```
asset('path_to_file', \App::environment() == 'production')
```

If you're in production, it will return true and load the asset via https, while returning false in development, loading via http.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5.3 you can just use the Laravel `asset()` helper function. It loads assets using the current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS)
You can find more details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset)